# Internal vs External Statement in Homotopy Type Theory

Tags: logic, deduction, type-theory

I would like to clarify the precise difference between the phrases "statement inside/ internal the theory" and "statement about the theory" in context of [Homotopy Type Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory).

A naive guess: can an 'internal statement' be understood as an abstract 'type' and the the decision about if the statement is true or not depends on if this type is 'inhabited' by some object (which would - if it exists-tautotologically have this type).

And in contrast, a "statement about the theory" shall be an inference rule, not more not less?

Is this interpretation correct or does it missing the point?

ADDENDUM: When I initially posed this question I forgot to add/ mention that probably the concept of a [judgment](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/judgment) should better reflect what might be regarded as an "external statement/ statement about the theory". So finally the partial question is: is "judgment" what should be recognized as synonymous term for "external statement"?

Comment: It is basically the distinction between object language and meta-language. With the object l of e.g. geometry we speak about properties of lines like parallelism. With the meta-language we speak of properties of the theory like consistency.

Comment: Internal statements are those expressible in a specified restricted language (type theory for HTT) and external ones can use full resources of the ambient theory (category theory for HTT). External statements are not limited to just inference rules and logic, one can talk about internal primitives as implemented by some category-theoretic constructions, for example. This is similar to what is done in model theory, ["elementary" sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence) "within" a model vs sentences about the model as described by set-theoretic constructions.

Comment: @Conifold: Could you explain what you mean by "expressible in a specified restricted language"? Do you by this "evertything" which semantically can be literally "written down" where semantics is fixed part of structure of the theory. Is the last formulation correct?

Comment: No, semantics uses ambient language. In a simpler example, in Peano arithmetic all you can do internally is write down algebraic formulas involving numbers, manipulate them, and use induction. You cannot talk about sets of numbers, maps, etc. In HTT you are restricted to some homotopy constructions expressed in type theory language.

Comment: @Conifold: Let's stick on this example with Peano arithmetics, I think this exactly hits the mark of my confusion. Internally, we can "write down algebraic formulas involving numbers, manipulate them, and use induction" because we have prescribed  "inference rules" which give us exactly the "building blocks", and internally we can constuct everything which is compatible with the prescribed inference rules from this "building blocks"? In this a correct interpretation for internal constructions (at least in realm of Peano aithmetics)?

Comment: In contrast, the set theory plays in this example the role of the ambient theory, and so as external statements we can use notion of sets, that's the issue?

Comment: In the context of Peano Arithmetic, an example of an external entity would be the set of all natural numbers (which does not exist in PA).  In the context of traditional set theory such as ZF, an external entity would be the collection of all sets, which is sometimes amusingly described in set theory textbooks as "the (non-existent) set of all sets".  Another example would be in Robinson's infinitesimal analysis, where the standard part "function" is an external entity.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: just to clarify, by Robinson's infinitesimal analysis you mean the nonstandard analysis, right?

Comment: Right. @user267839

Comment: "Inference rules" typically refer to purely logical side of a formal theory. Algebraic identities, induction, etc., would not typically be called that even though one combines them with logic to draw inferences. But if you want to extend the expression to non-logical rules and axioms as well then yes, this is roughly the idea.

Comment: @Conifold: but then keeping focus on this dichotomy between internal and external statements: Where do the "inference rules" "live" precisely in this context and "as what"? Sorry, if the formulation is a bit vague formulated. I not know where to fit these into the big picture distinguishing external and internal statements.

Comment: I am not sure what locating where "inference rules live" means. We limit expressive means and vocabulary, syntax and  "inference rules" codify that. They "live" in our heads, conventions, toolboxes. If this was some model, for example, this may reflect limited operational access. Say, statements "internal to thermodynamics" can trade in averaged quantities, like temperature and pressure, but not intimate that they are averages of microscopic mechanical characteristics. That would be external to thermodynamics and belong to its ambient theory, statistical mechanics.

Comment: @Conifold: my vague formulated question pursued to understand if the notion of "inference rules" is designed for the mechanism of "drawing conclusions" in internal or external world of the theory. But I think that the answer should be: both. Simple example from HtTT language: Let eg $x:A$ (that's an "external" statement; namely that $x$ has type  $A$. Analogously, $y:B$. Then there exist an inference rule implying $(x,y): A\times B $. This is again an external statement. But we also "constructed" by this inference an habitant of type $A\times B$, that's an internal operation, isn't it.

Comment: So one can say that "inference rules" are not sticking only on external or internal site; they are used internally and externally; that's what I meant when I asked where these "inference rules live" . Or does it missing the point?

Comment: @Conifold: Another point: You meantioned that "Inference rules typically refer to purely logical side of a formal theory". In turn: what would be an example for the opposite to the "purely logical side of a formal theory"? A guess: The construction process? ie construction of an inhabitant of a type?

Comment: "Inference rules" do function in both worlds, but not in the same way. Internally, they can only be applied 'mindlessly', to transform formulas, externally, they can be reasoned about as a subject (using "inference rules" of higher order in the ambient theory). It is the difference between running a program and analyzing it. Modern formal theories rarely codify any sort of construction processes explicitly, this is just informal jargon. But *modus ponens* and disjunction introduction are inference rules, while induction and algebraic identities are not.

Comment: @Conifold: About one point I'm still not completely sure. At the beginning you wrote that "internal statements are those expressible in a specified restricted language" in contrast to "nearly  unrestricted" ( of course in appropriate sense) external / meta theory, right so far? How do I concretely know what is allowed and what not (= restriction) in the internal theory, in contrast to the external theory? In other words, which "instances" or "entities" dictate to me what is internally allowed "to do" and what not? Can it be formalized?

Comment: Internal language is formally defined, anything that its syntax produces is internal, nothing else is. It is not done  by "restricting" richer external language, although informal descriptions may do that if the latter is more familiar to intended readers. Ultimately, you still need to produce a derivation in internal syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we have a formal theory, it is implicitly assumed that the theory under consideration (the object theory) is formalized in some other mathematical theory (the metatheory). In ordinary mathematics, we usually implicitly assume some set theory like ZFC as metatheory. Generally speaking, any theory which is expressive enough do mathematics in, can serve as metatheory. HoTT itself can also host ordinary mathematics, so it also works fine as metatheory. The same theory can be object theory and metatheory in different contexts.

Working in set theory as metatheory, the syntax of HoTT is a particular family of sets. There are many equivalent specifications of the syntax of HoTT (or any type theory for that matter), but we have at least:

- A set of contexts.
- For each context Γ, the set of types in that context; call it Ty(Γ).
- For each context Γ and each type A in Ty(Γ), the set of terms with type A; call it Tm(Γ, A).

An internal statement is a type, i.e. an element of Ty(Γ) for some Γ. An external statement is a statement of set theory. External statements can be anything, they don't have to talk about HoTT.

Comment: here you considered the special case where the metatheory is choosen to be the set theory. But if we think abstractly about an underlying metatheory of our type theory, is it true that the 'internal statements' are precisely the 'judgments'? Or, at least that the 'judgments' are examples for external statements, but not all external statements must be given as judgments?

Comment: The metatheory can be anything which can embed the syntax of HoTT, the choice of set theory is not essential. The metatheory could be another type theory as well. "Judgements" in the context of type theory are usually typing and equality. Using my definitions, judgmental equality of types/terms can be just set-theoretic equality, and a typing judgment is the proposition `t ∈ Tm(Γ,A)`. Internal statements are not judgments, they're types. Not all external statements are judgments.

Comment: Say we have type theory with a fixed metatheory. Does there exist a notion of extensions / inclusion relation witj respect to different meta theories of the fixed type theory or is a a meta theory a fixed additional data for a given type theory? In other words, does the method make sense to "extend" a meta theoty of a given type theory?

Comment: Why I'm asking this? You said judgment are external statements, but not all external statements ( living naturally in the overlying  meta theory) are judgments. So it seems to me that this would give rise to following natural question: Does there exist the "smallest" metatheory about the underlying internal theory with the distinguished property that all allowed external statements  there are "judgments"? In other words, the non judgmental external statements would firstly apear, when we extend this "smallest" meta theory to a bigger one with respect this hypothetical inclusion relation from

Comment: previous( more precisely now penultimate) comment?

Comment: This sounds like a question of [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics). I think it's interesting to look for e.g. the weakest theories which can embed HoTT in a sensible way, but I don't really understand how "the only meta-statements are object-theoretic judgements" would be meaningful or useful. Saying that we have "a set of object-theoretic types" only makes sense if "set" is sufficiently built up in the metatheory to match some informal intuitive notion of set.

Comment: The point with which I'm still a bit struggling is about the point that the meta theory may be the set theory. The problem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory#Differences_from_set_theory. It seems that having only rules but no axioms - which in turn set theory has - is the key feature of type theory. Therefore I'm not sure why this is consistent with the staement you made that the metatheory could be set theory. Or are we talking about different issues? Do you see how to resolve this confusion?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the confusion... The metatheory can be absolutely any theory that can serve as a foundation of general-purpose mathematics. When you do any kind of reasoning about the syntax of HoTT (not *in* the syntax of HoTT), say, prove normalization, that reasoning has to happen somewhere, and that somewhere is the metatheory.

Comment: so in the metatheory/external theory any kind of reasoning is"allowed" ' as long as it is allowed in the formalism of this "underlying" theory. But how do I know which methods / kinds of reasoning are allowed / not allowed in the *internal theory*? From where I "know" it? So far I understand it correctly, the so called "inference rules" provide "toolbox" of reasoning methods for internal *and* external worlds. But I not know what provides the tools to see which reasoning methods are specifically allowed internally only.

Comment: The internal type theory has a precise specification just like any other formal theory. Formally, when I say "HoTT", that refers to a concrete collection of type formers, computation rules, structural rules, etc. This is the same as when I say "ZFC" and I'm referring to a first-order logical theory with concrete axioms. Informally, "HoTT" can refer to a range of variations, like "set theory", e.g. I may include or exclude some type formers as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, think I got it now.

Comment: one nitpick: in the HoTT book ("the" book imaged in wiki link above) one emphasised several times when talking about the judgment a:A (so a metatheoretical statement) that this should be regarded as "a kind of" $a \in A$ from set theory. But note the "a kind of" annotation. So it seems that the underlying meta theory of the HoTT from the book is not really the set theory but something similar. Do you know what is the metatheory of the HoTT from this book? It seems to be something which has similarities with set theory as emphasised about, but not exactly the same

Comment: That comparison is just a didactic analogy, meant to teach working in HoTT (so, internally to HoTT) to people who are familiar with set theory. I don't think there's anything pertaining to metatheories here.

Comment: so if one not want to stick on set thery as underlying meta theory for didactical simplifications, but keeps an "abstract" meta theory in mind managing the external statements of the given HoTT, then on should think about this judgment a:A really just as an abstract statement which is expressible in the given meta theory, not more, not less?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that you have a time machine. You decide to journey into the future to see what advances have been made in Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT).

When you arrive, you discover a society where every discussion about HoTT is framed using the terms "internal" and "external" statements. These terms don't refer to anything physical, but rather to different perspectives on the theory itself.

An "internal statement" in HoTT, you learn, is a statement made within the framework of the theory. It's like stepping inside your time machine and saying, "I am in the time machine." These statements concern types and their properties. For instance, a statement like "for any types A and B, the type A -> B -> A is inhabited" would be an internal statement. It's about the objects (types and terms) that exist within the theory.

On the other hand, an "external statement" about HoTT is a statement made from an outside perspective, looking at the structure of the theory as a whole. It's like standing outside your time machine and saying, "The time machine has a door." These statements might concern the rules or axioms of the theory, or make claims about its consistency or other meta-properties.

Your naive guess is quite close to the mark. An internal statement can indeed be thought of as a type, and the truth of the statement corresponds to whether the type is inhabited. Your interpretation of an "external statement" isn't completely off, but it's perhaps a bit narrow. External statements might concern inference rules, but they can also concern other aspects of the theory's structure or behavior.

Remember, in this future society, these terms help theorists to communicate more effectively about aspects of HoTT. They allow for clear and precise discussions about the theory, just as the time machine allows for exhilarating journeys through time.

As you return to your own time and step out of your time machine, you carry this knowledge with you, ready to apply it to your continued studies in Homotopy Type Theory.

**A more direct answer**

Let's clear up some stuff here.

An "internal statement" in Homotopy Type Theory is indeed a statement about types and their inhabitants within the theory. It is essentially a proposition expressed in the language of the theory. For example, you might say "there exists a type A such that there is an inhabitant a of type A". This is an internal statement because it uses the objects and structure of the theory itself.

In HoTT and similar type theories, a proposition is identified with a type, and the proposition is said to be true if and only if there exists a term (or "object") of that type. This is called the "Curry-Howard correspondence" or "propositions as types" principle.

On the other hand, an "external statement" or a "statement about the theory" is a statement that is not expressed in the language of the theory, but rather in the meta-language in which we discuss the theory. For example, you might say "Homotopy Type Theory is consistent" or "Homotopy Type Theory has a certain model". These are external statements because they are about the theory, rather than being expressed within the theory.

The concept of "inference rules" you mention is related, but not exactly equivalent. Inference rules are indeed part of the meta-theory, in that they are rules for manipulating and reasoning about statements in the theory. However, not all external statements are inference rules; other external statements might concern properties of the theory as a whole, such as consistency or completeness.

Finally, as for your addendum, in type theory, a "judgment" is a technical term for a certain kind of assertion that can be made in the meta-theory. There are several kinds of judgments, like "is a type", "is a term of type", "are equal types", "are equal terms in a type", and so on. All of these are indeed "external" in the sense we have been discussing. But not all external statements are judgments (for instance, the statement "the theory is consistent" is not a judgment). So "judgments" and "external statements" are not synonymous, although there is an overlap.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm sorry, but unfortunately I missed to implement an important notion which should be definitely more closely to the notion of an "statement about the theory": the "judgment" (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/judgment). Reading you explanations about the concept of "external statement" through the glases of your thought experimen with th "time machine" it seems to me, that the notion of judgment comes in most closest way to it from the formal nomenclature of httt, doesn't it. Could you lose few words on this issue with judgment? Sorry for forgetting to mention it before

Comment: There are typically three kinds of judgments:

    Type judgments: These are of the form "A is a type".
    Term judgments: These are of the form "a is of type A".
    Equality judgments: These are of the form "a is equal to b in type A".

In this sense, judgments in type theory are more basic than statements. They are the fundamental assertions that we make in the theory, and they do not have truth values in the same way that statements do. Instead, they are part of the structure of the theory itself.

Comment: Returning to the time machine analogy, a judgment would be akin to a fundamental observation or assertion about the time machine. For example, an observation that "The time machine is a device capable of time travel" would be akin to a type judgment. An observation that "This is the time machine's control panel" would be akin to a term judgment. And an observation that "The time machine's current setting is equal to the year 2023" would be akin to an equality judgment.

Comment: So, if we were to fit judgments into the internal-external framework, they would most closely align with external statements, as they are about the structure and behavior of the theory itself, rather than about the objects within the theory. They are assertions we make from an outside perspective when we are describing, manipulating, or reasoning about the theory as a whole.

Comment: still, I'm a bit struggling with the analogy to this time maschine thought experiment, expecially why the statement "I am in the time machine" should be formally regarded as internal one, except that it is literally about "internal issues" :)? But what about for exampe the statement eg Does the time maschine contain a chair inside it? :) Wouldnt it cause ambiguity? Maybe following helps: Let's take a step back, what plays the role of a " type" in you time maschine analogy?

Comment: Maybe I was too swept away with developing an analogy and a more direct answer was needed. How about I edit the answer adding a "shorter answer"